# Refused to connect in Outlook Web add-in when trying to load any web page url

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am working on Outlook web add-in demo to show my demo add-in option inside the Outlook.
So will have a website portal that will work in any browsers.My add-in demo project is running fine and add-in name is appearing in Outlook. Now I need to load same website portal inside the web add-in in the whole web add-in window.
I have added the url in manifest file inside the Sourcelocation still is appearing like "Refused to connect" in task pane.

Could anyone assist me to do the same? How can i do that.

I am adding here my manifest, html file and taskpane screenshot.

[image: Manifest.xml]

[image: html file code to open url]

[image: Taskpane error "Refused to connect"]

Comment: It is not clear how you are trying to load the web application inside the task pane. But I'd suggest starting from [Addressing same-origin policy limitations in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations). Also I'd suggest reviewing the http messages in Fiddler. Maybe there you will find out any information that can shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can we use any url ("e.g https://www.google.com/") or we need to url hosted on azure?

Comment: You can use any URL, but don't forget to specify it in the add-in manifest file.

Comment: Hey @EugeneAstafiev, I have added url in manifest file and also tried to open same url with iframe in html but still url is not opening, I have updated the questions and added screenshots, 
Could you please check once and help me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your URL to the AppDomain element in your manifest for it to appear in your add-in pane:

The following XML manifest example hosts its main add-in page in the https://www.contoso.com domain as specified in the SourceLocation element. It also specifies the https://www.northwindtraders.com domain in an AppDomain element within the AppDomains element list. If the add-in goes to a page in the [www.northwindtraders.com](http://www.northwindtraders.com) domain, that page opens in the add-in pane, even in Office desktop.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <!--IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for each add-in. If you copy this manifest ensure that you change this id to your own GUID. -->
  <Id>c6890c26-5bbb-40ed-a321-37f07909a2f0</Id>
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso, Ltd</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Northwind Traders Excel" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Search Northwind Traders data from Excel"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="[Insert the URL of a page that provides support information for the app]" />
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://www.northwindtraders.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/search_app/Default.aspx" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>
```

This link should help with more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-in-manifests?tabs=tabid-1#specify-domains-you-want-to-open-in-the-add-in-window